# Creating a Friendly ID with validate false

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, friendly-id

I'm using `friendly_id` in my app but I'm splitting up the registration process so that it is split into individual steps.

As a result when the record is first created, it is done so with validation disabled, and then the subsequent steps of the registration process fills in the blank, then at the final step, I call update which validates just in case anything has been missed along the way.

Unfortunately though no slug is being created for my record. From some digging, it appears that the friendly id is being generated `before_validation`. So it's never being called!

How can I get around this?

I have seen in the docs that you can set the slug to nil and then save it and it will re-generate, but when I do that before calling update, it throws a validation message because the slug is nil!! I have also tried the following before calling the update but still with no joy:

```
if @channel.slug.blank?
  @channel.slug = nil
  @channel.save
end
```

Any thoughts on what I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it in the end, you need to add a ! after save so the following worked:

```
if @channel.slug.blank?
    @channel.slug = nil
    @channel.save!
end
```

Bit of a shame I have to make an extra DB call but at least it is working!

Many thanks for those that looked

Answer (score 9):

You can trigger the friendly_id generation manually by doing

```
object.send :set_slug
```

and then to save without validation

```
object.save(:validate => false)
```